# modify the width of an imageView with animation

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, uiimageview, width

I have an image "image1" which is a UIButton and what I want is that if I touch this button, the width of the image is multiplied by two (with animation)not the height just the width.
sorry for my english I'm french :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly easy with block animation. Simply try:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                       animations:^{ 
                         CGRect newRect = imageView.frame;
                         int movementToTheLeft = imageView.frame.size.width / 2;
                         newRect.size.width *= 2;
                         newRect.origin.x -= movementToTheLeft;
                         imageView.frame = newRect;
                       }
                       completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                          animations:^{ 
                                            NSLog(@"Scaled!");// Anything can go in  this completion block, it should be used for any logic you need after the animation.
                                          } 
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                            ;
                                          }];
```

This should scale your imageView's width by 2. Hope that helps!

Comment: Good answer except for the 2nd animateWithDuration in the completion block. Did you really mean that?

Comment: I usually use it for having a boolean variable which stops the user from pressing the button until the animation is complete. It is also good to trigger other animations or notifications to your code as well. You don't really need it, it's just my preference. And yeah, the 1.0 is a bit too big for this example!

Comment: this code doesn't work, because when I touch the button my button move to the right and its width doesn't change, it simply moves to the right

Comment: You are moving an imageView right? Put the movement in in the animation as well, and that should take care of it.

Comment: Also, you have to make sure that the image changes size to fit the imageView. Play around with the different options for the content mode in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The old fashioned way (not recommended after iOS 4.0, but still works):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"widen" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
CGRect newRect = imageView.frame;
newRect.width *= 2;
imageView.frame = newRect;
 // ... set more parameters if desired
[UIView commitAnimations];
```